# Accessing Calls to Mocked Class functions

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I have written a custom class to mock a general API client in a codebase so that I can centrally and easily mock all of the class methods for unit testing. This is working great so far, however I am looking for a way to track individual calls to each class method. Right now that only trackable call via Mock is the initial class instantiation.

Here is the mock class:

```
from faker import Factory

faker = Factory.create()

class MockAPIClass
  def get_some_data(self, data):
    return f"{data} - {faker.pyint()}"
```

Then in my util file:

```
def func_to_test_that_calls_client(arg):
  client = regular_api_client()
  return client.get_some_data(arg)
```

Then in my unit tests:

```
from unittest import mock
from django.test import TransactionTestCase
from .file import MockAPIClass

from .util import func_to_test_that_calls_client

class TestUils(TransactionTestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.api_call_patcher = mock.patch('path.to.mocked.class.instantiation')
    self.patch_api = self.api_call_patcher.start()
    self.mock_api = MockAPIClass()  # this done so that the mocked class can be referenced below
    self.patch_api.return_value = self.mock_api

  def tearDown(self):
    mock.patch.stopall()

  def test_util_func(self):
    res = func_to_test_that_calls_client("test")

    self.assertTrue(res)
    self.patch_api.assert_called_once()
```

The above functions exactly as expected and intended. However, inside of the funciton `func_to_test_that_calls_client`, the original client is instantiated then the class method `get_some_data()` is called. With this implementation, I have no visibility into the call stack of the class methods like that function, only the parent instantiation of the class. I would like to be able to see for example that `func_to_test_that_calls_client` was called with `"test"` with this current implementation. Is there a way to do this with mock or some other python trick?

Comment: "I have no visibility into the call stack of the class methods like that function" I am having a hard time understanding exactly what you mean. What do you mean by "the class methods like that function"? The function is not a class method, an instance method, or any other kind of method. What do you mean by "visibility into the call stack"?

Comment: "the original client is instantiated" I'm sorry, are you saying the mocking *does or does not work*?

Comment: "This is working great so far, however I am looking for a way to track individual calls to each class method. Right now that only trackable call via Mock is the initial class instantiation." So, I think by "tracking" you mean being abloe to use parts of the [mock API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) like `assert_called_once` etc. But of course you can't, because `MockAPIClass` doesn't implement any of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard `Mock` object (which is what `patch` uses by default) works fine.  There's no need to build your own special mock class.

Using this as a simulated version of your `util.py` (I needed to add a dummy `regular_api_client` to have a target for `patch`):

```
regular_api_client = lambda: None

def func_to_test_that_calls_client(arg):
  client = regular_api_client()
  return client.get_some_data(arg)
```

this simple test seems to do what you're after:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from util import func_to_test_that_calls_client

def test_util_func():
    with patch('util.regular_api_client') as mock_client_class:
        mock_client = mock_client_class()
        func_to_test_that_calls_client("test")
        mock_client.get_some_data.assert_called_with("test")
```

Note that you can validate that the above test works (I always second-guess myself with mock methods on whether I actually called a "real" mock method or another mock, heh) by changing `assert_called_with("test")` to `assert_called_with("something else")` and seeing that the test now fails:

```
E           AssertionError: expected call not found.
E           Expected: get_some_data('something else')
E           Actual: get_some_data('test')
```

Comment: Your comment didn't directly answer my question, but it made me realize that I had a bug in my code and that once I fixed that I could use your method outlined here to access mock call stacks for class methods. Thanks!